# ERROR: Service 'api-gateway' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder931060141/api-gateway: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having trouble building a Go-based Docker project.  My overall directory structure looks like:

```
api-gateway
│  ├─handler
│  └─resource
   --Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile contains:

```sh
FROM alpine:3.2
ADD api-gateway /api-gateway
ADD resource/pri_key.pem resource/pub_key.pem /resource/
#ADD resource/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
VOLUME /resource/
ENTRYPOINT [ "/api-gateway" ]
```

Even though I'm using ADD to include a file in the image, I'm still getting an error.  `api-gateway` is a directory that includes the `Dockerfile` inside.

```
D:\FileWithDocument\ExtraCodeProject\shop-micro-master>docker-compose up
Building api-gateway
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:3.2
 ---> 98f5f2d17bd1
Step 2/5 : ADD api-gateway /api-gateway
ERROR: Service 'api-gateway' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder931060141/api-gateway: no such file or directory
```

I use Docker Desktop in Windows.
Docker Engine version is:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

When i download the github project and run docker build, it still outputs this error.

> ERROR: Service 'api-gateway' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder931060141/api-gateway: no such file or directory

Comment: First, you write `ADD resource/...`, then you write `VOLUME /resource/` are you sure is the same path? one path start with `/` and the other one no.

Comment: I just download the github project,not change any thing" ADD api-gateway /api-gateway" is the error sentence.

Comment: Please format your question using code blocks as it makes it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `docker build`, the directory you give it becomes the *context directory*; you can only refer to file paths within that directory tree, and any file paths in `COPY` or `ADD` statements are always relative to that directory.  That means if you're running `docker build` from the directory named `api-gateway` that contains the `Dockerfile`, `.` is the same directory.  Your Dockerfile might look more like:

```sh
FROM alpine:3.2

# This will create the directory in the image if it
# doesn't already exist.
WORKDIR /api-gateway

# Copy the entire current directory into the image.
# (Prefer COPY to ADD, unless you specifically want
# automatic archive extraction or HTTP fetches.)
COPY . .

# Copy in some additional files.
# (Remember that anyone who has the image can extract any
# file from it: this leaks a private key.)
COPY resource/pri_key.pem resource/pub_key.pem /resource/
COPY resource/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

# Set the default command to launch.
# (Prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT: it is easier to get a debugging
# container with a shell, and there is a useful pattern that
# uses an ENTRYPOINT wrapper to do first-time setup before
# launching the CMD.)
CMD ["/api-gateway/handler"]
```

If you see a "docker-builder12345678/...: no such file or directory" error, you should always interpret the path components after the long number as relative to the directory you passed to `docker build`.

Comment: I was add a directory to image.Not just a file or files.